The debugger crashes randomly during debugging in Godot 4.21
During debugging, at a random stage of debugging, the game closes without any errors, and the debugging process stops. There are no errors following this. Without debugging, the game runs normally and does not close during operation.
I've reviewed the code multiple times, but pinpointing the source of the error seems impossible because the crash occurs at absolutely any stage of debugging. I'm out of ideas. Has anyone encountered similar behavior?
Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9m1fz-Kz0w4&ab_channel=Lingondary

Please create an issue on github if a similar issue doesn't already exist. Thanks!

I made a bug report, but I guess it won't be considered as I can't provide a minimal reproduction project for the reason that I don't understand where the problem occurs. The crash is reproduced randomly, logging and step-by-step code review do not give any results. But I have attached all my project on Git. I will hope and wait)

You might try building Godot from source to get a debug build, hopefully that could give you more information about the crash.

That was a good idea
<couldn't map PC to fn name> 32 times and crash. Now at least there is something to start from when searching for problems.

Whoever has this problem, look into using C# and GDScript together in the same project. Using the godot debug build helped me to guess the culprit of the crash. I can't name the error itself, but excluding C# from the project eliminated the crash.

I encountered the same behavior and found the root cause for my issue. The cause for me is that one of my autoload object is freed, resulting the debugger doing a hard cast on the freed object, hence the crash.
I created a github issue for it.
https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/92607
